# Importing __init__ of subpackage from inside subpackage, Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-module

My file structure is

```
package
+-__init__.py
+-subPackage
  +-__init__.py
  +-testFile.ipynb
```

I'm trying to import a class in the subPackage.**init**.py file from the subPackage.testFile.ipynb.

I've tried:

```
from __init__ import ClassName
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
from pyomo.environ import *
```

to import any modules from environ subpackage of pyomo package.

Therefore, I think the following might work to import any module inside the subpackage in your regard:

```
from package.subpackage import *
```

Please insert name of package and subpackage in the line above and try.

Comment: No luck, says no module names "package". This works for you when you use it in a .ipynb file from inside your subpackage?